# Class Name not getting changed in IE 7, 8 and chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to change class name of two elements during onload.

Here is my code for the same :

```
    var browserName=navigator.appName;
    var tfElem = document.getElementById("TTlExpct");
    var blTfElem = document.getElementById("BTLExpct");
    if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    {
        tfElem.className ="pn-tf";
        blTfElem.className ="pn-tf active";
        }
    else
    {
        tfElem.setAttribute('class', 'pn-tf');
        blTfElem.setAttribute('class', 'pn-tf active');
        }
```

The else block takes care of the code if its not IE, in mozilla, this is working fine, class name is getting set.

Its not working in IE7 and IE8

and

in chrome, it works only if i reload the page again.

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the implementation of `setAttribute` in old versions of IE. In newer versions of IE that bug may be emulated if you do not use a Doctype that triggers standards mode.

Replace:

```
foo.setAttribute('class', value);
```

With:

```
foo.className = value;
```

Do this **everywhere**. Don't try to do browser detection. All browsers that support `setAttribute('class', value)` also support `foo.className = value`.

The code in your question should be rewritten as:

```
var tfElem = document.getElementById("TTlExpct");
var blTfElem = document.getElementById("BTLExpct");
tfElem.className ="pn-tf";
blTfElem.className ="pn-tf active";
```

Comment: I am using proper doc type and if you look at the code that i have provided, u will see that i am using foo.className = value; in the ie detection block.

Comment: I tried it out , mozilla has no problem, but IE 7,8 and chrome don't work. So i am back to square one .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight — In that case, I'm betting the problem has something to do with either how you are running this piece of code, or with how you are testing if the classes are being added. (i.e. something not disclosed in the question).

Comment: probably, not sure though how the same piece of code can work in MF and be such a pain in the butt in IE and chrome .

Comment: Ok so, i found out the issue, seems the class that i was setting for tfElem is causing the problem. In practicality , i just needed to change it to a blank class name and everything fell in place for all the browsers. Thanks Quentin, for pointing out the obvious . Upvoted and accepted.