# How can I get the current selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have the following code,

```
$(".selector1, .selector2, .selector3").click(function() {
    switch(CURRENT SELECTOR) {

    }
});
```

I need the current selector inside for a switch statement, such as "selector1", "selector2". The selector option in jQuery is deprecated so that can not be used. I am also using jquery 1.4.2 so please try to keep it under that.

Comment: `jquery 4.2`???

Comment: can you add the relevant html and maybe make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @ArunPJohny opps. I meant 1.4.2

Comment: @dax You really need that to solve this problem? Its irrelevant.

Comment: it's just generally a good idea to add all the necessary code - and if  it's so simple that you don't feel you need to add code, why are you asking a question about it rather than doing your own research?

Comment: @dax Stop arguing semantics. If you dont know the answer than go look at a different question. There is nothing else needed for this. The code needed is there. All your doing is wasting space.

Comment: FYI you could use one of the solutions with `var selno = $(this).attr("class").replace(/.*\bselector([0-9]).*/,'$1');` where `selno` is 1,2 or 3

Comment: See **working demo** in my answer when using multiple classes http://stackoverflow.com/a/19252586/1873446

Answer (score 3):

Use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to get the class value of clicked element:

```
$(".selector1, .selector2, .selector3").click(function() {
    var elem_class = $(this).attr("class");
    switch(elem_class) {

    }
});
```

If elements have more than one class you can do:

```
$(".selector1, .selector2, .selector3").click(function() {
    var arr = ["selector1", "selector2", "selector3"];
    var arr2 = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    var choosen_one = false;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
          if(arr[i] === arr2[j]) {
             choosen_one = arr2[j];
             break;
          }
       }
       if(choosen_one) {
           break;
       }
    }

    switch(choosen_one) {

    }
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxuhg/)

**Reference:**

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: CURRENT SELECTOR doesn't seem to be a good name for a variable, don't you think so ?

Comment: What if there are more than one classes?

Comment: This wont work if the class is "blah1 blah2" and I need just the class in the selector.

Comment: The problem here also is, if you have multiple classes for any of these, otherwise this could work

Comment: Why does everyone need to use `$(this).attr('class')`? `this.className` works all the way back to IE6.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Because $(this).attr is using jQuery which trys to account for browser inconsistencies.

Comment: @Metropolis there is no browser inconsistencies in this case. your answer is correct on the whole (its the reason i use jQuery), but you're safe here to use vanilla JS (which is using jQuery smartly). here is a good reference for this case => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834045/class-name-not-getting-changed-in-ie-7-8-and-chrome

Comment: @PlantTheIdea There may not be browser inconsistencies right now. But what if in the future there are? Would you want to have to go through an entire huge application and waste time and money updating it all because theres nothing wrong right now? Or would you want to use jQuery and have them fix it in one spot?

Comment: @Metropolis did you check the demo?

Comment: @Metropolis - you're aware of the fact that using a set version of jQuery only accounts for browser inconsistencies at the time of release ... not future versions. but then, why bother knowing how something actually works?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea The is ridiculously obvious I would think. But is it not easier to upgrade to a newer version of jQuery than it is to go through hundreds of files and account for it? Im not sure why this is even a debate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are four ways to handle your issue:

1) **class** *if you have just one per element*:

```
$(".selector1, .selector2, .selector3").click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("class")) {

    }
});
```

2) **unique IDs** *not good, if you'd like to use it multiple times*

```
$("#selector1, #selector2, #selector3").click(function() {
    switch($(this).attr("id")) {

    }
});
```

3) **unique selector**

```
$("[data-selector=selector1], [data-selector=selector2], [data-selector=selector3]").click(function() {
    switch($(this).data("selector")) {

    }
});
```

4) **multiple event handlers**:

```
$(".selector1").click(function() {
    myFunction($(this));
});

$(".selector2").click(function() {
    myFunction($(this));
});

$(".selector3").click(function() {
    myFunction($(this));
});

function myFunction(myThis) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Yeah #4 is what I had before this. I was trying to cut that down. Maybe the 3rd one.....Trying to look into that.

Comment: @Metropolis I prefer 4, it's more code but very clear. I principally separate event handling from the functions where the logic happens. If you write your code object oriented, you could create a method for event handling.

Comment: In my case though, All of my click functions are doing almost the exact same thing, except for one variable. So that is why I was trying to cut it down, so that everything is in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.4.2, why can't you use the `.selector` property? It wasn't deprecated until 1.7.

Comment: If its deprecated why would I want to use something I am going to have to come back and remove later?